# How can I sort photos/videos by its "Date modified" on Windows?

Tags: batch, windows

I used phockup to sort photos/videos from my phone's backup. A lot of them ended up in the "unknown" folder since they don't have "date taken". Now I want to sort files from "unknown" by their "date modification" to folders where my sorted files are (e.g. 2023/January/01-January). What should I use?

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to use XNView MP. When you are in browser mode click icon like two arrows and select your sorting wishes.
[image]

Then select photos by desired group and move them with drag and drop.

Or use Alt+M to move them in folder (the folder will be created if not exist)

Comment: That's good but I'm looking for something automatic

Comment: @janlu, maybe you can check here: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use exiftool for this, with a commandline something like this:

```
exiftool '-Directory<FileModifyDate' -d c:\target\%Y%m%d -r c:\source
```

This uses the file system modify date. Use `ModifyDate` if you want to use the EXIF ModifyDate.
You can use exiftool to list all EXIF tags your files actually contain.

See [strftime](https://cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/strftime/) for the date format options to cobble together a directory name to your wishes.